# Grand total in cart price

Tags: magento-1.9

For some reason, all the sudden I noticed the grand total price was the same as my shopping cart product price. So basically something that should say 3.96 in the cart is a lot more. It's adding the tax to my product price in the cart summary.

Was there a setting that I apparently missed??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify whether catalog product prices are displayed including or excluding tax.

```
  System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings -> Catalog Prices
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Magento's tax functionality really does bring new meaning to the word 'weird'